# How to create half-circle menu (sub item) with CSS, Java Script on mobile web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, geometry

I want to use a half-circle menu when I surf the mobile web with right hand.

Can somebody teach me how to create half-circle menu (sub item) with CSS, Java Script on mobile web?

the photo link:

1.There is a half-circle menu button, it could be opened and closed.

[image]

2.When I click one of main level item, the sub item could be drop down.

[image]

Sincerely thanks.

Comment: Circles can be achieve with `border-radius`. You don't have to handle click event in Javascript, `:active` pseudo class with child selector can do that.

Comment: I notice that you can read Chinese, did you know this site? http://m.taobao.com/ This isn't a spam, I just wanna show you the example of it's navigation (see the lower left corner). It uses sprite image to display the circle.

Comment: @ChiChou - 我看得懂你那行文字…

Comment: @AdairChen - The best way is to use SVG to create them so that the elements wouldn't be a rectangle.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 在这里写非英文会被人吐槽的

Comment: @ChiChou - Perhaps you are right... 對了，你有訪問過[StackOverflow的中文chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12327/chinese)嗎?

Answer (score 8):

You can use SVG to achieve this design in HTML5 since most mobile browsers nowadays support SVG.

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/dQBzd/show

### Code

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/dQBzd/

```
function drawMenu(selected) {
    $("svg").empty();
    var texts = ["國際", "生活", "文教", "健康", "科技", "新奇"],
        subTexts = [
            ["這裡", "有一大堆", "目錄"],
            ["A", "B", "C"],
            ["A", "B", "C"],
            ["A", "B", "C"],
            ["資訊3C", "科學發展", "自然環境", "科技熱門"],
            ["A", "B", "C"]
        ];

    var isSelected = selected !== undefined,
        columns = texts.length,
        angle = 12,                       //Angle (degree) of each menu
        subAngle = 8,                     //Angle (degree) of each submenu
        angleOut = (180 - angle * columns - (isSelected ? subAngle * subTexts[selected].length : 0)) / 2 * Math.PI / 180;
    angle *= Math.PI / 180;
    subAngle *= Math.PI / 180;

    var originX = 300,
        originY = 300,
        upper = getXY(angleOut, 220),
        lower = getXY(Math.PI - angleOut, 220);

    $("<path/>").attr("d", [
        "M", upper[0], upper[1],
        "L", originX, originY,
        "L", lower[0], lower[1]
    ].join(" ")).appendTo("svg");

    for (var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        var group = $("<g>").addClass("item button").attr("data-menu", i).appendTo("svg");
        group.addClass(isSelected && selected == i ? "selected" : "");
        var angleCur = angleOut + angle * i +
            ((isSelected && selected < i) ? subAngle * subTexts[selected].length : 0),
            originX = 300,
            originY = 300,
            topL = getXY(angleCur, 300),
            topR = getXY(angleCur, 220),
            bottL = getXY(angleCur + angle, 300),
            bottR = getXY(angleCur + angle, 220);
        createSlice([topL, topR, bottL, bottR], group);
        $("<text>").html(texts[i]).attr({
            x: (topL[0] + topR[0] + bottL[0] + bottR[0]) / 4 - 50 / 2,
            y: (topL[1] + topR[1] + bottL[1] + bottR[1]) / 4 + 40 / 4
        }).appendTo(group);
        createSlice([
            getXY(angleCur, 220), getXY(angleCur, 50),
            getXY(angleCur + angle, 220), getXY(angleCur + angle, 50)
        ], group);
        if (isSelected && i == selected) {
            for (var j = 0; j < subTexts[selected].length; j++) {
                var angleSub = angleCur + angle + subAngle * j,
                    g = $("<g>").addClass("subItem").appendTo("svg");
                createSlice([
                    getXY(angleSub, 220), getXY(angleSub, 50),
                    getXY(angleCur + angle + subAngle * (j + 1), 220),
                    getXY(angleCur + angle + subAngle * (j + 1), 50)
                ], g);
                $("<text>").html(subTexts[selected][j]).attr({
                    x: 100,
                    y: 316,
                    transform: "rotate(" + [-((angleSub) * 180 / Math.PI - 90),
                        300, 300
                    ].join(",") + ")"
                }).appendTo(g);
            }
        }
    }

    (function () {
        var group = $("<g>").addClass("menu button").appendTo("svg"),
            top = getXY(angleOut, 50),
            bott = getXY(Math.PI - angleOut, 50);
        $("<path/>").attr("d", [
            "M", top[0], top[1],
            "L", originX, originY,
            "L", bott[0], bott[1],
            "A", 50, 50, angle * columns, 0, 1, top[0], top[1],
            "Z"
        ].join(" ")).addClass("button").appendTo(group);
        $("<text>").html("menu").attr({
            x: 255,
            y: 303
        }).appendTo(group);
    })();

    $("body").html($("body").html());

    $("svg g.item").click(function () {
        drawMenu(
            $(this).attr("class").indexOf("selected")!==-1?
            undefined:
            +$(this).data("menu")
        );
    });
}

function getXY(angle, len) {
    return [300 - len * Math.sin(angle),
        300 - len * Math.cos(angle)];
}

function createSlice(coords, parent) {
    var angle = 12 * Math.PI / 180,
        topL = coords[0],
        topR = coords[1],
        bottL = coords[2],
        bottR = coords[3];
    $("<path/>").attr("d", [
        "M", topL[0], topL[1],
        "L", topR[0], topR[1],
        "A", 300, 300, angle, 0, 0, bottR[0], bottR[1],
        "L", bottL[0], bottL[1],
        "A", 300, 300, angle, 0, 1, topL[0], topL[1],
        "Z"
    ].join(" ")).addClass("button").appendTo(parent);
}

drawMenu();   //You can also do drawMenu(index), where "index" is the selected menu
```

### Basic Components

[Paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) (shapes):

```
<path/>
```

[Texts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Texts):

```
<text>Text</text>
```

In my example, all SVG nodes are JavaScript-generated in order to calculate the correct coordinates for the lines.

### Ain't nobody got time for dat! [image]

Not everyone is willing to or has the patient to mess with these nasty SVG nodes. Don't worry, [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) to the rescue!

Raphaël is a rich vector graphic library that let you draw *and* animate vector graphics with very few code. If you are that kind of person then you should definitely try this out.